# Error With sharing image

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image

I want to share an image using ACTION_SEND. So basically when the users taps on an image and selects "share image" it should send the image selected,
So when testing, it takes me to which app I want to use to share with i.e whatsapp, Facebook, email etc. And then when selecting either one, it then says "sharing failed, please try again." I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work. However I have the same code to display image file full screen with ACTION_VIEW and that seems to work great but not with sharing.

```
public void Onmulti2 (View view) {

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    share.setType("image/*");

    String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/ahmed.jpg";

    File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image!"));

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

First stored my image in external storage

```
private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        String fname = "image.jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.e("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                        Log.e("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

## . ##

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ahmed);
    SaveImage(img);

}
```

then load my image from external storage then shared it .

```
    public void Onmulti2 (View view) {

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/saved_images/image.jpg"));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share image using"));
}
```

### note

got the path from emulator

```
01-29 23:25:47.478 32648-32659/com.company.integrations E/ExternalStorage: Scanned /storage/emulated/0/saved_images/image.jpg:
01-29 23:25:47.478 32648-32659/com.company.integrations E/ExternalStorage: -> uri=content://media/external/images/media/106290
```

Answer (score 1):

set type image/jpg instead of image/*

```
public void Onmulti2 (View view) {

Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

share.setType("image/jpg");

String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "/ahmed.jpg";

File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);

Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image!"));
```

}

Comment: Try it, String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
        + "/ahmed.jpg";

Comment: is your image in root directory ?

Comment: still the same error ... my image in drawable folder

Comment: than your taking imagepath in wrong manner this method is applies on image taking from phone directory not from drawbles

Answer (score 0):

**step 1: First add permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**step 2: edit**

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");    
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(imagePath);
```